# Snap to next div on first scroll only

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has a large feature section (100% window), and below it a variable height section of content. I the page to scroll to that next div when it detects a mouse wheel event, but then lets the user continue scrolling up or down afterwards without it snapping back to the top of the div.

I understand there is some combo of mousewheel, smoothscroll, snaptoo, that might work, but I haven't seen anything that only executes on the first event and then dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `one` is fine.

```
$(window).one("scroll", function(){
    var top = $(".nextDiv").offset().top;
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: top}, 200);
});
```

[jQuery one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, maybe some sort of conflict with the window height portion? http://jsfiddle.net/picard102/9fPnt/

Comment: fixed it, `window` has no scrollTop property, use `body` instead [http://jsfiddle.net/9fPnt/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/9fPnt/2/)